How does a constant have a vertical tangent and be differentiable?
We know that the derivative of a function is the slope of it's tangent line, and the tangent line is a line that intersects it only once. However, since a constant is parallel to the x axis, the tangent would need to be perpendicular to intersect it only once. But, that means that it's a vertical tangent, hence undefined. How does that work? I may sound stupid, but I am very confused.

It's not true that the tangent line intersects the curve only once. Consider the tangent line at $0$ of $\cos x$ for example. It will intersect the graph infinitely many times.

A more general definition of a tangent line is the line that intersects a curve at a point but becomes indistinguishable from the curve as you zoom in closer and closer to the point. There is really no nice geometric way of defining tangent lines of general curves without limits

Why would the tangent need to be perpendicular to intersect it only once? Any finite, nonzero slope line would intersect the constant line exactly once

The definition of a tangent as something that "just touches" the curve but does not cross it is limited and antiquated - under such a definition, inflection points have no tangent. The modern definition is the line passing through two infinitely close points on the curve. There simply is no requirement that a tangent can only touch the curve once.

"Intersects the curve only once" is a baby explanation for a tangent line.  I hope an actual textbook has a better definition for this.

The line $y=ax+b$ is tangent to the graph of a differentiable function $f$ at $x=x_0$ iff$f'(x_0)=a$ and $f(x_0)=b$ . That does not mean that there is only one point of contact between the line and the curve. Maybe you are thinking of the definition of a tangent to a circle in which case, yes they only intersect once. But that's not the case for some functions

@NuclearHoagie Oh I see! My bad. I think I understand now. Since there is no line that can just touch the line once, so the slope is 0. I feel like a kindergartner now.

@TalhaMughal we all get confused at times. Shake it off.
